# Python: install module on correct path in OSX

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pycharm

I'm trying to use scrapy with python 2.7. I've installed scrapy succesfully, but when I try to import the module I get a message saying "unknown module".

So I have some super basic questions regarding installing python modules in pycharm:

1) How do I make sure that a module is installed on the correct project path? I spent a week recently installing pyqt4 and I really want to get a good understanding of how directories/paths work, so that I don't have to enter random commands in my terminal and hope I get lucky.

2) Why is it possible to install some modules directly through Pycharm in the project interpeter and do you need to install others manually with pip or homebrew?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your OSX version number has a typo.  10.16 doesn't exit yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default location for packages installed via `pip` for Python 2.7 on Mac OS X is `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`.

You can see where packages are located using `pip show <package_name>`. For example, if I wanted to know where my `requests` package is located, I would run `pip show requests`.

1. If you are running a python script using Python 2.7, the packages
   you are referencing should exist in the path mentioned above (if the
   packages are installed correctly). If you want to maintain more
   control over your projects and their packages/versions, you should
   use `virtualenv`. Virtualenv creates environments that have their own
   installation directories that don't share packages with other
   `virtualenv` environments. This is a very popular option many people
   use when managing projects.
2. Most packages should be installable across PyCharm and `pip` as they both look to the Python Package Index (PyPI) as their repository by default. Make sure you don't have another repository set if you want results from `pip` and PyCharm to be consistent.

Hope this helps!

Resources:

1. [pip show](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/)
2. [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/#)
3. [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi)